# Can you oxidize gold using only oxygen?

Tags: redox, transition-metals, reactivity

I keep reading that gold does not react with oxygen, but I also see information about [gold Oxides (ie: aurous oxide, Au2O and auric oxide, Au2O3)](https://www.911metallurgist.com/blog/gold-oxides#:%7E:text=Fulminating%20Gold-,Aurous%20Oxide%2C%20Au2O,moist%2C%20but%20greyish%20when%20dry.)

Knowing that there is a way of getting gold oxide using multiple steps and additional chemicals (ie. decomposing aurous chloride), is there a way of getting gold oxide without any intermediate steps? Can you produce gold oxide if you have a closed system with gold and oxygen and the ability to control the amount of energy in the system?

Comment: No, it's not possible, why ask when you already heard that?

Comment: @Mithoron b/c it sounds more like what someone would say in relation to what normal people and jewlers subject gold to on a day to day basis and not what a chemist might subject gold to in a controlled experiment.

Comment: @Mithoron if this is the correct answer please post it so I can accept it.

Comment: Getting back to the post. With the downvotes this post is receiving and what I thought was a simple question, can I assume that even though chemists are not posting an answer the correct answer is that "Yes the coloquial statement that pure gold does not react with air is true regardless of the energy in the environment."

Comment: @Tolure See https://doi.org/10.1038/179212a0: gold does react with pure oxygen at elevated temperatures (~900 °C), albeit very slowly. And please refine whether you are asking about *oxygen* or air since the answers will be vastly different.

Comment: Thank you @andselisk for your comment. My question is specific to oxygen, I should of pharsed my comment to be "Yes the coloquial statement that pure gold does not react with *oxygen* is true regardless of the energy in the environment." Could you post that as an answer.

Comment: I bet I can implant oxygen ions and synthesize it, but I don’t think you mean that quite.

Comment: Well, [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/94692/17368) says gold does not reacts with oxygen at all. [Above 160 C, any gold oxide (including intermediate oxides) will decompose.](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/67963/decomposition-of-gold-hydroxide/68211#68211)

Comment: The most common gold oxide $\ce{Au2O3.xH2O}$ is made by action of alkali on aqueous gold(III) solution. Even gold is resistant to ozone up to 100 °C.

Comment: The most stable gold oxide Au2O3(anhydrous) reportedly decomposes above 160 Deg C.

Comment: I'm sure that gold can react with oxygen even at room temperature if the oxygen pressure is high enough. As in, hundreds of thousands of atmospheres or more.

Comment: Note: There were two answers to this question, where my sulfite/oxgen/copper/chloride path was deleted as not relevant to the chemical oxidation of gold involving oxygen. Please note this August 2021 commercial gold dissolution article: "Simultaneous sulfide oxidation and gold dissolution by cyanide-free leaching from refractory and double refractory gold concentrates" 
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0892687521002715 and also note that sulfite is not radicalized absence oxygen, transition metal and chloride. Does anyone know how to undelete?

Comment: @AJKOER Gold oxidation is far wider scope than gold reaction explicitly  just with oxygen.

Comment: Agreed, as to why in my cited 'answer', I argued that it was not, albeit, a simple direct oxygen path! Those curious in my cited chemistry will have to now demand an undelete.  Note: material presented therein is contained in an in process patent filing, as full disclosure, so happy if it stays deleted.

Comment: @AJKOER chill out. Sometimes good answers lose because they do not fit the question precisely enough. If you can see hidden answers, migrate to [this Math SE q](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4412856/what-is-12-fold-stampfli-inflation-tiling-and-where-how-can-i-recognize-it-in-th) and observe my own misfortune.

Comment: No, need, am happy that part of my Patent's content is now secret. If anyone undeletes, read it quickly as on notification, I will delete. However, this not a matter of a 'good answer' as the ascribed rated answer cites nano gold on a support? At least, I addressed  the intent of the question (regular gold metal) and disclosed needed agents, and honestly asserted it was not an answer (implying there is no such pathway and that still is my opinion).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, yes — if you cheat a little by using atomic oxygen. [Ono and Cuenya[1]](https://doi.org/10.1021/jp711277u) report that combining gold nanoparticles with atomic oxygen at 150 K results in gold oxide formation, and the oxidized nanoparticles release the oxygen as $\ce{O2}$ upon heating. The authors further note that the nano-oxide is more stable on a silica support than on a titania support, suggesting a catalytic effect of the latter material.

This finding is relevant to electrochemical oxidation of water on gold anodes, where the electrode is oxidized by the oxygen atoms from water molecules prior to evolving $\ce{O2}$ [[2]](https://doi.org/10.1039/C3SC50301A).

**References**

1. Luis K. Ono and Beatriz Roldan Cuenya (2008). "Formation and Thermal Stability of Au2O3 on Gold Nanoparticles:  Size and Support Effects". *J. Phys. Chem. C*, **112**, 12, 4676–4686. https://doi.org/10.1021/jp711277u
2. Oscar Diaz-Morales, Federico Calle-Vallejo, Casper de Muncka  and  Marc T. M. Koper (2013). "Electrochemical water splitting by gold: evidence for an oxide decomposition mechanism".
   *Chem. Sci.*, **4**, 2334-2343. https://doi.org/10.1039/C3SC50301A

Comment: Huh, does atomic count? Then ozone also would, I guess? BTW how are they making it?

Comment: @mithoron the experimental section refers to O2 plasma, so tge atomic oxygen appears to have cone from energizing O2 to make the plasma. Energy input would be acceptable since many overall spontaneous reactions need such input (e.g. heating) to be observed.